# Ошибка пути JDK в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я пользуюсь Linux Mint 17 "Qiana" и установил IntelliJ IDEA для изучения Java и разработки под Android. Когда я пытаюсь задать путь к JDK при создании нового Java-проекта, мне он возвращает ошибку `The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK`. Путь, который я указываю для JDK - `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386`. Также пытался указать путь `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/` и далее с `/bin` или `/jre/bin` для обоих вариантов, но ничто не сработало. Устанавливал IDEA под `root`. Никак не могу понять, в чём моя ошибка, если она есть, и как ее исправить без особого шаманства :(

Comment: Вы добавили JAVA_HOME в /etc/environment ?

Comment: да, дело в том, что до этого на компьютере стояла Eclipse, и с ней не было никаких проблем :(

Comment: пропишите в environment `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"` потом `source  /etc/environment` перезапустите систему полностью и попробуйте. Так же у вас может быть неверно выбран JDK, посмотрите в этом разделе http://i.imgur.com/uVdBNTi.png

Comment: @Bleser дело в том, что у меня уже это было прописано, вот здесь: http://postimg.org/image/nswj9du2p/

Comment: Хорошо, а в gradle( i.imgur.com/uVdBNTi.png) выбрано JDK? Если не получится, то придется попробовать переустановить под `user`, пробовал ставить в `root` начались капризы.

Comment: @Bleser дело в том, что изначально я ставил под `user`, и была эта же ошибка, поэтому решил переустановить под `root`

Comment: @Bleser какая-то магия, теперь сработало на `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/`, но кнопка `next` неактивна

Comment: можно скрин посмотреть?

Comment: @Bleser http://postimg.org/image/f6mgx94zl/ пожалуйста

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39464/discussion-between-bleser-and-alexnikolaev94).

Comment: @Bleser и вот настройки gradle http://postimg.org/image/5wpil2d8h/

Answer (score 2):

При установке intellij idea на Linux нужно проделать следующие шаги:

1. [Установка JDK](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-ubuntu-apt-get-ru)
2. full reboot
3. создать\открыть проект и выбрать JDK который установили п.1

Comment: я все это проделала и не один раз, выдает ошибку и не видит путь

Comment: @анна какую ошибку? что выводит `echo $JAVA_HOME`?

Answer (score 1):

Такое ощущение, что Intellij, запущенный от user не видит папки ,созданные от root, в т.ч. и **/usr/lib/jvm/***.

Не помог даже `ln` от user из домашней папки на **/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle**
Плюнул и скопировал sdk из **/usr/lib/jvm/** в домашнюю папку под юзером - только тогда заработало.